# ABRecordRef check if record is Facebook-only?

Tags: ios, abrecord

When looping through all address book contacts is there a way to see whether a record is a Facebook-only record? That is address book records that are inserted when adding Facebook in iOS Settings.

I am trying to skip these records and only look at records that are user-entered or synced from other sources.

Thank you

Comment: while looping through address book contacts, loop through individual groups.. All Facebook contacts remain in FACEBOOK group.. that way u can restrict ur program.

Comment: Is there a way to see which group an ABRecord belongs to, since I am not looping through contacts on a per-group basis, but I use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()`

Answer (score 3):

With this snipplet you can detect Facebook-Contacts:

```
+ (BOOL)isPersonFacebookContact:(ABRecordRef)person {
    ABMultiValueRef instantMessage = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);

    BOOL returnValue = NO;

    if (instantMessage) {
        for (NSInteger i=0 ; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(instantMessage); i++) {
            CFDictionaryRef instantMessageValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(instantMessage, i);
            CFStringRef instantMessageString = CFDictionaryGetValue(instantMessageValue, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey);

            if (CFStringCompare(instantMessageString, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
                returnValue = YES;
            }

            CFRelease(instantMessageString);
            CFRelease(instantMessageValue);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(instantMessage);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Would this be realiable enough that it's definitely ONLY the natively-inserted FB entries?

Comment: No sorry, but there is no "Facebook-Contact" flag :(
You could try after this check to edit the contact and when you are not able to add a new Phone number or something, it should be a Facebook-Contact!

Comment: Unfortunately it allows me to edit the contact and save as well without throwing any error other than the fact the data doesn't appear in the address book.

Comment: I get an error when calling ABRecordSetValue() .... I also think that the return value is FALSE .... but I have no device with facebook account in my range at the moment ... sry :D

Answer (score 0):

Every `ABPerson` record belongs to exactly one `ABSource`.

When you iterate through all the person records, call `ABPersonCopySource(person)` on each. Facebook records should all be associated with a particular source record. I'm not sure how to identify it: possibly the `kABSourceNameProperty` for that source record will contain "Facebook".

Comment: I tried this, but there isn't a "Facebook" source name, unfortunately. It just outputs a blank string :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, Its doesn't detect facebook directly but you could evaluate the sources further and is there is a social profile linked that is facebook, and a linked contact to facebook contact then you would be pretty certain thats its facebook. I used this to get only the contacts I could write back to. Users can change their default contact creation account, but based on my test Facebook only contacts source never matches the ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource.

```
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(ab , kABSourceTypeLocal);
AllContacts = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFArrayGetCount(people), people);


// Remove all the contacts that we cant write back to
for (int i = CFArrayGetCount(AllContacts)-1; i >-1  ; i--)
{
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(AllContacts, i );
    if((ABPersonCopySource(person) !=ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(ab)))
    {
        NSString *fName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));

        DLog(@"Removed a read only contact %@ %@", fName , lName);
        CFArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(AllContacts, i);
    }// else its not something you can write back to, like facebook, twitter.
    CFRelease(person);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> New version (without memory licks):

```
+ (BOOL)isPersonFacebookContact:(ABRecordRef)person {
    ABMultiValueRef instantMessage = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);

    BOOL returnValue = NO;

    if (instantMessage) {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(instantMessage); i++) {
            CFDictionaryRef instantMessageValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(instantMessage, i);
            CFStringRef instantMessageString = CFDictionaryGetValue(instantMessageValue, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey);

            if (instantMessageString) {
                if (CFStringCompare(instantMessageString, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceFacebook, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
                    returnValue = YES;
                }
            }
            CFRelease(instantMessageValue);
        }

        CFRelease(instantMessage);
    }

    return returnValue; }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.